# Exclude Bitlocker encrypted USB from USB storage disable GPO in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, usb, bitlocker

I have a USB drive to move files between a domain and a standalone PC. The USB drive is encrypted with BitLocker and can be used between a domain client pc and the standalone.

On my domain there is a USB disable GPO from which I was forced to exclude that client PC in order to use the BitLocker encrypted USB drive.

Is there a way to put an exclusion to that GPO using as trigger the BitLocker decryption of the USB drive? My Domain Controller is Windows Server 2012R2 and the client and the standalone are both Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: `Is there a way to put an exclusion to that GPO using as trigger the bitlocker decryption of the USB drive?` no, Group Policy isn't going to do this. Typically the finer granularity of portable mass storage disablement is offloaded to the EDR solution (Carbon Black, CrowdStrike), or some custom internal solution. Additionally, you have almost *zero* information on the drive when it is locked and hasn't unlocked yet, which is typical for thumb drives and BitLocker To Go.

Comment: You can use GPOs to define which serial numbers of USB devices are whitelisted and disallow the rest. That's possible, but nothing related to Bitlocker is applicable for exclusions other than the (well-known?) GPO "make read-only unless it's bitlocked".